# Python Selenium can't find elements when browser changes

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a script to auto fill some fields with Selenium. I'm running into problems where if the script clicks on a button that navigates from the original url, then Python can't find the elements on the new page.

For example: If I have selenium navigate to this landing page first (https://www.emedny.org) and click on the log in for ePaces, and then try to fill out the form, I get an error. This code is what I run:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(path)

keyed_path = r'https://www.emedny.org'
browser.get(keyed_path)

epaces_login = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#targetContainer > a:nth-child(3)')
epaces_login.click()

username = browser.find_element_by_id('Username')
username.send_keys('test')
```

This code opens up https://www.emedny.org, clicks on a button which takes us to a log in page (https://www.emedny.org/epaces), and *is supposed to* enter in a username on the page. However, I get this error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Username"}
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

But, if I skip the landing page and open up the log in page directly, like in this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(path)

keyed_path = r'https://www.emedny.org/epaces'
browser.get(keyed_path)

username = browser.find_element_by_id('Username')
username.send_keys('test')
```

Then the code runs well, and updates the username field as expected. It seems as though Selenium might be searching for that id on the opening url *only*.

Here's the HTML for the username field:

```
<input name="Username" type="text" maxlength="8" id="Username" class="inputText" size="13" onchange="javascript:validate(this)">
```

Any suggestions? I've tried id, XPath, css selector, name, etc. Same error each time.

EDIT: The link that selenium clicks first opens up a new tab. Could that be part of the issue?

Comment: have you tried finding the current `url` using `browser.current_url`?

Comment: conversely, you might need to `implicitly wait` the browser. for further reading: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: @SreetamDas I didn't use current_url because I thought that was just a way to access the url as a string. I'll try the wait methods. Thank you

Comment: @SreetamDas I tried both explicit and implicit waits for 45 seconds, both timed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It's because the link being clicked on opened up a new tab. Selenium was searching for the elements on the previous tab. I used `window_handles` and `switch_to_window` like this:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(path)


keyed_path = r'https://www.emedny.org'
browser.get(keyed_path)

print(browser.window_handles)

epaces_login = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#targetContainer > a:nth-child(3)')
epaces_login.click()


browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[1])

username = browser.find_element_by_id('Username')

username.send_keys('test')
```

Comment: just a suggestion @jaredstuft, try using [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/); it's much more lightweight, and you wouldn't have faced the new-tab error in the first place using it :)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I was using Selenium... are you seeing something different? It's a very new library for me so I'm not sure about best practices.

Comment: Hmm, how about using [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org) instead of the Chrome driver then? It is a `headless` driver.